# Django circular import error between models and signal callback functions

Tags: django

There seem to be quite a few issues related to circular import errors just with models, but I seem to be getting a similar problem with my model and signal callbacks. I'm fairly new to Django, so in all likelihood it's more to do with me not structuring my app correctly. Some code:

badges/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from tasks import badgeaward_callback

class Award(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    award_date = models.DateTimeField('date awarded',default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class Points(models.Model):
    POINT_TYPES = (
        ('signup', 'Sign up'),
        ...etc...
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField('date created',default=datetime.now)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    data = models.TextField(blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=POINT_TYPES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

models.signals.post_save.connect(badgeaward_callback, sender=Award)
```

badges/tasks.py

```
from badges.models import Points

def badgeaward_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    award = kwargs.get('award')

    p = Points()
    p.points = 100
    p.type = 'badgeawarded'
    p.description = award.description
    p.user = award.user
    p.save()
```

So, models is importing badgeaward_callback (this is the error I get: cannot import name badgeaward_callback), but tasks is importing Points model - I assume this is the root cause of my error.

Any advice on how I should be structuring my app is much appreciated. Should I just put my badgesaward_callback into models.py? That works (well, no more error), but is it a good approach when later I may be adding quite a few more callback functions?

Comment: You can fix this if you add `from badges.models import Points` within your function `badgeaward_callback` (A lazy approach)

Comment: Thanks Aamir - I'd seen that approach, but it doesn't really feel right to me - was kinda hoping there may be a nicer way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of better structure, instead of `tasks.py` rename it `signals.py` and from models.py

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(badgeaward_callback, sender=Award)
```

move this line to `signals.py` at end. Then you don't require the import `from tasks import badgeaward_callback` in models.py

Answer (score 1):

You can move `models.signals.post_save.connect(badgeaward_callback, sender=Award)` to `tasks.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from badges.models import Award, Points

def badgeaward_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    award = kwargs.get('award')

    p = Points()
    p.points = 100
    p.type = 'badgeawarded'
    p.description = award.description
    p.user = award.user
    p.save()

models.signals.post_save.connect(badgeaward_callback, sender=Award)
```

then import `tasks` in the `__init__.py` of your models package.